# How to assign function defaults to R .GlobalEnv

Tags: r

For some debugging purpose i often need to have function default values in the global environment.

`f<-function(a=1,b=T,c) {}`

`formals(f)` returns a pairlist with a "symbol" type values. So, i cannot just `attach(as.list(formals(f)))`...

Comment: Try `f <<- function(a=1,b=T,c) {}`.

Comment: It will create _f_ in global environment. I need _a_ and _b_ there.

Comment: Could you just save the defaults outside the function like this: `x =1
y=T

f<-function(a=x,b=y,c) {}`

Comment: It may be interesting, but i need them with their inside function names. This way i still don't have _a_ and _b_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ff <- f
body(ff) <- quote(environment())
```

Now this will put them in the global environment:

```
list2env(as.list(ff()), .GlobalEnv)
```

or this will attach them to the search path:

```
attach(ff())
```

### Note 1

`a` and `b` are normal variables but `c` is represented by a missing value so although it will be in the global environment or search path you can't print it; however, you can query whether or not it is such a variable like this:

```
inherits(try(c, silent = TRUE), "try-error")
## [1] TRUE
```

That expression will be FALSE for variables having a value.

### Note 2

To only copy only the arguments having defaults to the global environment:

```
ff <- f
body(ff) <- quote({
  L <- as.list(environment())
  is_missing <- sapply(names(L), function(x) {
    x <- as.list(ff)[[x]]
    missing(x)
  })
  L[! is_missing]
})
list2env(ff(), .GlobalEnv)
```

or to attach them replace the last line with:

```
attach(ff())
```

Comment: Brilliant! Is there a way to test missings inside a list to exclude them? 
`typeof(as.list(ff())[[1]])=="symbol"` works, but i'm not sure...

Comment: add_args<-function(f) {    
    body(f) <- quote(environment())  
    list2env(as.list(f())[!sapply(as.list(f()),is.symbol)] , .GlobalEnv)  
    }

Comment: See the added Note 2.